# get MemSQL command input and output types

Tags: singlestore, database-metadata

Is there any way to get a list of the input parameters and their types and output parameters and their types for any MemSQL SQL command? I am primarily interested in select statements and stored procedure calls. I don't want to execute the command to get the information. I am open to any automate-able solutions that I can use. Ideally, it would be a stored procedure I could call or a native library I could wrap. I want the [datatype info](http://docs.memsql.com/latest/ref/datatypes/) for each parameter.

With Microsoft SQL Server, this information can be obtained from `sys.sp_describe_first_result_set` as described in [New Metadata Discovery Features in SQL Server 2012](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/new-metadata-discovery-features-in-sql-server-2012/).